# Append to pagination links URL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

How can I append:

```
#products
```

To the end of the pagination URL used by Laravels pagination links method so I could get the following in the address bar?:

```
products?page=3#products
```

This is so that my mobile users and people with low resolution desktops don't have to scroll down the page every time they navigate using the pagination links.

---

This is what I have in my config/view:

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Pagination View
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This view will be used to render the pagination link output, and can
    | be easily customized here to show any view you like. A clean view
    | compatible with Twitter's Bootstrap is given to you by default.
    |
    */

    'pagination' => 'products.ProductPresenter',
```

And I'm getting:

```
Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception
```

My presenter as per Laravel documentation:

```
class ProductPresenter extends Illuminate\Pagination\Presenter {

    public function getActivePageWrapper($text)
    {
        return '<li class="current"><a href="">'.$text.'</a></li>';
    }

    public function getDisabledTextWrapper($text)
    {
        return '<li class="unavailable"><a href="">'.$text.'</a></li>';
    }

    public function getPageLinkWrapper($url, $page, $rel = null)
    {
        return '<li><a href="'.$url.'">'.$page.'</a></li>';
    }

}
```

Comment: To change the pagination being generated by Laravel by making your own [Custom Presenter](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination#custom-presenters).

Comment: @Bogdan I followed that but I'm getting 'No hint path defined for [ProductPresenter]' :(

Comment: Please post the code you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `fragment()`

```
{{$products->fragment('products')->links();}}
```

Comment: above is the answer to your question. if you have more than one question, post them in a different question. it will be easier to answer then.

Comment: how are you outputing the presenter btw?

Comment: Sorry, I thought your answer was to be used with the custom presenter stuff. This works :)